# Are the pronoun-looking forms of quire attested?

Tags: classical-latin, example-request, ambiguity

The verb *quire* is conjugated like *ire*, and there are some forms that look like an interrogative or relative pronoun.
Those forms are *quīs* and *quī*.
Are these attested in classical literature?

These are awfully hard to search due to the ubiquitous pronouns.
I find it possible that these forms were avoided — and perhaps there wasn't much use for the imperative in the first place — so it is not clear whether they would have been used.

Comment: I didn't even know *quīre* existed until I saw this question…

Comment: Plautus uses *quivi* quite often, but I can't find *qui*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Generally, **such forms were rare** and were used mostly used with negative particles *ne* or *non*. After all, *queo* was backformed from *nequeo*.

cf. Kühner and Holzweissig 1912/1994: "Viele Formen von diesen Verben [queo and nequeo - Alex B.] kommen nur selten vor und in der guten Prosa gar nicht" (para 200), the forms quis and quit are given in [square brackets] there, which means they were very infrequent;

also "Das Verbe *queo* wird von den guten Klassikern nicht haüfig gebraucht (nie von Cäsar), cf. Leumann "bezeugt vorwiegend bei Plautus und Terenz und noch bei Lukrez, also altlateinisch" (p. 512).

From Leumann 1977:

“age, iam mitto, ignosco: aetate **non quis** optuerier.” (Plautus, Mostellaria 840)

“tu, ut occepisti, tantum quantum **quis** fuge
atque Herculem inuoca.” (Plautus, Mostellaria, 527)

Kühner and Holzweissig 1912/1994 also mention that *non quis* is found in Pl. Pers. 287 Truc. 2 3, 5 Lucr. 1, 751 and Hor. Serm. 2. 7, 92; *non quit* Pl. Trin. 504. Aul. 2. 8, 21 and Ter. Hec. 183.

A quick search on LASLA gives the following (NB: I didn't manually check the examples):

CATULLUS    Carmina 61,66   quit

HORATIUS    Sermones    2,7,92  quis

LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 1,751   quis
LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 3,554   quit
LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 3,646   quit
LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 4,1164  quit
LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 4,1166  quit
LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 5,152   quit
LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 6,431   quit
LUCRETIUS   De Rerum Natura 6,555   quit

PLAUTUS Aulularia   391 quit
PLAUTUS Curculio    173 quit

SENECA  Agamemnon   130 quit

For a more comprehensive analysis we'll have to look it up in the TLL and Neue and Wagener (volume 3).

Comment: Thanks! this is very thorough. Two questions: (1) Is *quit* relevant? Additional information is not harmful, but it does not quite look like a pronoun, unless it is a variant of *quid*. (2) What is LASLA?

Comment: LASLA Opera Latina

Answer (score 4):

L&S give a reference to Horace for "non quis".

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dqueo

Comment: I'm surprised he didn't use *nequis*, which is very common.

Comment: Cicero never used nequire, although he used "non quire" often, according to L&S:queo.